# Would it be helpful to be able to link to specific answers?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I saw a really hilarious (and correct) answer to a question and wanted to link directly to it because of the way answers "float" up and down based on votes. And for me to find the URL I had to go to the posters profile, page through all of their responses (thank God it wasn't Jon Skeet), and find the link. Is there an easier way? If not could we have a link to the question posted in the question header so we can copy it's destination?(The way that I have seen that liked best was just the number displayed linking to the correct URL so you could just click the URL and copy it.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's already possible - if you see an answer you want to link to, just right-click the "share" link and copy the URL. When you visit this URL you will be automatically taken to that answer.

Comment: OK, I feel really really dumb right now:) So before I start another dumb question... Can you favorite an certain answer?

Comment: you can favorite questions but not answers

Comment: Think I'll put that one on uservoice.

Comment: I actually added a request to UserVoice for favoriting an answer on 06.27.2009: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/238022-mark-an-answer-as-favorite

Comment: Mark answer as favorite was ported to meta a few weeks ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite

Answer (score 2):

I think it could be nice if there would be automatic linking to other answers/questions, such as Youtube's automatic link to a specific time in a video (in comments, if you type 1:25 for instance, it will be automatically hyperlinked to jump to the 1m25s mark in the video).

There could be some RegEx parsing added to recognize question/answer ID and automatically hyperlinking it, for example:

> ...This question was answered
>   [here][#156]

could be translated into:

> ...This question was answered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156/)

This, however, would not be practical, because nobody remembers question IDs. Therefore, while it would be nice to have, this approach would not work well.

Perhaps if the search was improved, specific answers could be found more efficiently...

Answer (score 2):

There is a "share | edit | flag" link cluster at the bottom of every answer.  The "share" one is a link to that specific answer.
(Kyle Cronin's answer was once correct, but the relevant link is now "share" (not "link").

You can

- right-click "share" it, and copy the address from the right-click menu (as Kyle Cronin describes in the originally correct answer) or
- just click it (left-click), and copy the address from the "sharing" dialog box.