# Trade rep for air miles

Tags: discussion, reputation, fun

I'd like to trade my reputation for air miles on a 1:1 basis.  I think Jeff and company should look into incentive programs that airline companies offer businesses for air miles.

<strike>I could then fulfill my Stack Overflow long dream of meeting Jon Skeet in person.</strike>*

Jeff, make it so!

[image]

*Turns out I'd need a lot more rep to get to Europe, and comments below appear to suggest that Jon is difficult to meet.

Comment: If you're going to say "Make it so!" you should at least have a picture of Jean Luc Picard, if not the entire crew from The Next Generation. I mean, seriously. He's the best captain ever.

Comment: @Jean - The deed has been did'd

Comment: is someone not getting enough work to do?

Comment: Best Captain Ever!

Comment: @Jeff: There's always time for Star Trek!

Comment: Even if this program existed, what makes you think that you would be able to meet the honorable Mr. Skeet?

Comment: @Jeff You realize, this site runs on programmers that aren't getting enough work to do...

Comment: @Chester - *Oh sure, just dash my dreams like so many clams upon the rocks of reality!*  http://www.ehow.com/about_5437183_many-needed-fly-paris-airways.html  *I'm going to need a lot more Rep to get to Europe...*

Comment: @pollyana - I hope that your dreams are met and you are greeted with open arms...  I'm just pointing out some obvious issues with your goal...  Getting to the UK is like 20% of the battle...

Comment: I'm still curious why airline miles are considered so blatantly offensive...

Comment: @AdamDavis I'll say hi to Mr Skeet for you tonight, as he's at our nexgen event :)

Comment: @Skuld I'll sit over here being totally jealous and stuff.  Oooh, there's hotpockets in the fridge!  brb...

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question. Maybe the suggestion in it is not very good, but it's not off-topic.

Answer (score 17):

Why would I need air miles when I can simply order my transporter chief to take me anywhere in the world with the push of a button, or when I can simply order my android helmsman to take me across the galaxy in the blink of an eye?

I wouldn't trade my reputation as Star Fleet's greatest captain for anything!

Stack Overflow: The final frontier
These are the voyages of the awesome guy Welbog
His continuing mission:
To explore strange, new ideas
To seek out new noobs and new suggestions
To boldly answer what no one has answered before!
(duuun da da duuun da da duuuuun *[that's the Star Trek: The Next Generation theme]*)

Comment: THERE ... ARE ... FOUR ... LIGHTS!

Comment: Looks like this post pushed Welblog over 10k. Oh the irony!

Comment: I've been at 10k for like a week, you silly Targ.

Comment: How many Enterprises did Picard destroy anyway?

Comment: Depends on whether you count alternate timelines or not...

Comment: Of course you have to count alternate timelines.

Comment: Hello there! I don't believe we've met!

Comment: @Brad: That would be somewhere in the area of infinity then, wouldn't it?

Comment: Warp me to Halifax!

Comment: When did you get an android for a helmsman?  I thought he was your Operations Officer.

Answer (score 6):

This seems like a joke, but seriously, wouldn't it be cool to be able to trade some of that excess rep for cool stuff like SO t-shirts*, mugs and stickers?

As long as we're not giving out rep to other users, I'm okay with converting rep into some more usable form of currency. What's a poor soul to do after they hit 10k anyway?

*<sub>Come on, picture it with me: "I hit 10k rep on Stack Overflow and all I got was this lousy t-shirt."</sub>

Comment: "I hit 10k and all I got was this lousy Telerix license"

Comment: @squillman: "Telerik"

Comment: Names changed to protect the innocent.