# Have you considered turning the stackoverflow reputation into a real currency?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Trade rep for air miles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37062/trade-rep-for-air-miles)
>   [How to convert your Stackoverflow's reputation into money?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30982/how-to-convert-your-stackoverflows-reputation-into-money)

The idea is ultimately monetizing the stackoverflow reputation so that people can actually buy/sell services/goods and other stuff using the stackoverflow reputation. 
In a first phase this can be used only among stackoverflow users but in time the reputation can be exported so that in can be used outside the stackoverflow system. It's like what banks do now...
In the end a currency is a way to measure the value somebody feeds into the system, and also how trustworthy that person is, and this is pretty much the same thing reputation is doing. 
So why not?

Update:

The benefit of this would be that people who spend a lot of their energies providing value ( earning reputation ) would actually be able to benefit from their effort in the real world.

Comment: But why? What benefit would this have?

Comment: [No.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30982/how-to-convert-your-stackoverflows-reputation-into-money)

Comment: So what you're saying is, you are selling out your reputation? Just like in the real world where you build trust, then sabotage it for money? (Because on trading, you're losing "trust")

Answer (score 3):

I will purchase your excess rep at a rate of one US dollar per ten thousand reputation points. Given that there is no easy way to transfer rep, this will involve the sale of your account to me.

Once I obtain your account, I will love it, and pet it, and name it <strike>George</strike> Pollyanna.

Comment: The idea was to get rid of the FED...

Comment: @Zer banks have a habit of coming down *very* hard on serious alternative currency systems :)

Comment: @What But this is nothing serious, it's just a bunch of programmers fooling around... ;)

Comment: Haha Pollyanna is much better. You've got me.. I'm too much of an idealist. Anyway.. as the identity management systems are winning ground, reputation management is the next thing and probably after that... the flourishing of alternative currencies..( it will be harder and harder to hide or to cheat..)