# Can I have a pension?

Tags: discussion, reputation, community

I am getting old and I need money. I bet many people do, but for some reason they prefer not to speak about it. Over 8 years at Stack Overflow I scored 11k rep and some badges.

[image: my rep]

There are not many answers there, as you may see below. It is roughly 64 rep per answer.

[image: my 8 years]

I like discovering things and going deeper into the matter. Like everybody else, I guess. But doing this is not fun anymore. Because companies need to do things fast. It is stressful, and I am not that stress resistant as every company wants. I also find it hard to work on problems that I don't find interesting, like doing the same bash script that was written 1000 times before by every and each developer who faced the same problem. This is my primary motivation in life - doing things properly once, to save time on scale, so that somebody else can spend this time better. This also makes me an awful employee, the one who misses deadlines and is not as effective as everybody else. Impostor is not a syndrome, it is a pressure, and I can not withstand it.

This is a long post for Stack Overflow. It is about getting some money for my reputation if anything that I did has any value to anyone. There are mining farms extracting crypto currency every N minutes, some of them burn energy, some do not. There are grants from Mozilla, USAID, Horizon 2020 but these are not accessible for someone who just digging in software problems. The competition for those is fierce, and it requires you to know beforehand what you will be doing.

I tried to help Gratipay as a platform that can be used to sustain ourselves, but it was shut down by FinCEN who over this years together with PayPal and other previous generation mafia invented rules that we can not compete with. I was involved in blockchain in the past year, but that didn't make secure. It is exciting to be there, but not so exciting to realize that I can not support myself and my family.

If I provided some value, is it possible to convert that value to something that will keep me alive? Or it doesn't matter for this site? If it was not me, then somebody else who has time and money would do this.

(sorry if I won't reply soon, bringing this up is exhausting, and I need to rest a bit)

Comment: What should [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) get then? A knighthood? (He's British)

Comment: 11k is really not that much to be honest, especially for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Mari-LouA he should probably just get Britain.

Comment: Why was my previous comment deleted? I suggested that the OP asked his question on SE Workplace, I was not mocking them. If their wholly unrealistic reference to receiving a pension for SE were removed and they instead asked what someone with their skills and experience but who finds deadlines particularly stressful (some actually thrive on that challenge), could do.

Comment: Did you consider using a code mentoring site instead of Stack Overflow? There you can contribute your knowledge in return for a small fee. Or heck, if you don't feel 1 on 1 is for you, start a Patreon and set up a site where you distribute your expert knowledge on certain topics at your own pace. I'm happily supporting some Unity3d developers myself for example.

Comment: Where would the money come from?

Comment: Also related: [Have you considered turning the stackoverflow reputation into a real currency?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83956/278094)

Comment: pretty disappointed with the -19 tbh. The point has been made and OP is obviously not trying to troll ...

Comment: @Mari-LouA I once considered having all of Jon's badges minted out of actual metals on a miniature scale (bronze / gold / silver) respectively. But, even at a 100:1 scale, he'd still topple over forward if he were to wear them all, and that's not because he's clumsy.

Comment: @Magisch A post can be not useful for reasons other than somoene trolling.  Downvotes aren't just for trolls.  In fact, downvotes aren't even the right tool for actual trolls.  Flagging would be the right tool for a post that's actually trolling.  And just because several others have already reflected their opinion of the quality of a post doesn't mean future readers should be prohibited from sharing *their* opinion of it's quality.

Comment: Apologies for mangled second comment earlier but it was rushed. Sadly, it's occurred to me that this could be a form of sardonic hoax... I hope not. Luckily, Tim's answer is extremely helpful and useful, so it should help anyone in a similar situation.

Comment: "bringing this up is exhausting, and I need to rest a bit"... :-0 Well now i know why you requires a pension.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Sounds like you need to get into the world known as *consulting*. There, you don't actually really *do anything*, you just charge a ton of money to tell companies how they *should* be doing stuff. It's kinda like retirement, except that you still need to answer your email and bring yourself to install and use Skype.

While you work on that, I highly suggest that you take a look at [some of the open positions our clients have posted](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) to see if any of them interest you. While I can't vouch for every hiring manager individually, we work very patiently with our customers to help them understand things we understand *as* programmers *about* programmers. So, it (as a platform) and the jobs that our clients post tend to be of substantially higher quality than the grind you're talking about.

Also, [we're hiring](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here), and we never poke people with sharp sticks. I used to be a systems and embedded engineer until I got sick of the stress and death marches, just like you have. Maybe you'd enjoy a *different* kinda challenge where having a developer background would give you an advantage? Sounds like you're pretty fed up and sick of it; I've been there.

Alas, I can't cash in your rep. But, we wuv you and want you to  succeed, so I've made you a letter of recommendation. Well, *sort of* a letter (I am so gonna regret the existence of Photoshop after this):

[image: Picture of Tim Post holding a paper sign that encourages companies to interview our valued user, the OP]

And I ***want*** you to get out there and explore other possibilities, because being done with one thing doesn't always mean being ready to start something else until you feel inspired.

So here's me helping you feel inspired:

[image: Tim Post giving a thumbs up sign]

Now, ***go get out there***. If, and this is a *really* big if, you manage to get an interview at a job you'll likely love, I'll send you a nice T-shirt to wear for good luck, and some other goodies for you to fidget with in the waiting room (we have some curiously click-y pens!) You're welcome to email me *once that happens* using the address in my profile.

We want the best for you and want to support you, but sometimes that means steering you in a direction that's a little harder than the one you were headed. A pension from us is barely sustainable, we can barely afford Joel's coffee needs. But you finding a better *field* where you could thrive? That's sustainable.

Good luck to you, our best to your family, and keep being awesome. It's gonna get better if you head in a better direction; it's bound to :)

Comment: Gahh I wish I could leave bounties on closed questions for this answer. This is incredibly heartfelt for what could've been just another run of the mill heavily downvoted meta question. You've definitely made at least one person's day a little better. Thanks for spreading the love, Tim.

Comment: Wait, there are *clicky* pens? I have the ones with caps but TIL you have *clicky* pens.  I wish the store still existed..

Comment: Clicky sharpies too. The little trapdoor ones

Answer (score 8):

Have you considered requesting donations in your profile description? Honestly it probably won't help, especially with only 11k reputation, but it's more likely that you'll get *something* out of it. There is no possible way Stack Exchange will actually give you a pension, no matter how much reputation you accumulate. Not only is that not their business model, but frankly, 11k is not a lot (especially on SO).