# Favourite answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mark Answer as Favorite / Star](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star)

I would find it *very* useful, if we could have not only favourite questions but also favourite *answers*. It's just that there threads with *loads* of answers, and it is not always the best scored answers that I like. So every time I need to refer to the answer, I have to browse through many posts *looking* for it.

Comment: +1 for proper spelling of *favourite* (and general agreement with the suggestion).

Comment: Welcome to Meta, Albus!  I groaned when I saw this because I thought it was going to be a "what're your favorite SO answers of all time?" poll/list thing.  But this is a good idea.  Unfortunately it's already been considered and declined: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star

Answer (score 0):

+1 from me - quite often I've made a note of a question, as a favourite, and wished that I could do the same with specific answers rather than having to store a browser based favourite (from the "link" permalink at the bottom of each answer). Particularly as without plugins, browser based favourties aren't portable.

If there was provided a way to favourite answers, I'd like to see the UI able to aggregate them by not only question (quite often I find parts of more than one answer useful), but also by tag. By tag would be useful specifically because when I'm investigating a problem, or learning something new, there's shared tags and thus it'd be a valuable way to be able to navigate favourite answers.