# Keeping track of changes to a question v/s keeping track of good answers

Tags: discussion, search, bookmarks

There have been [feature-requests in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star) about option to favourite answers only but that has been declined

So, currently there is only one way to achieve both these things (at least only one way that I am aware of) and that is through favouriting the questions themselves.

I currently use favourites to keep track of questions whose answers I will be interested in tracking - as i get the intimation about changes for my favourites and already my favourites are going into multiple pages

If i also start adding any question which has an answer that is interesting / something i want to keep for reference as a favourite, i see two problems

- Going through my favourites will be more painful as they will drastically increase in number.
- Specifically for answers, this is compounded by the fact that my interest in a specific answer might not be so easy to associate from the questions title which is really the only thing that i am looking at in the favourites page (unless i click that link to see the actual question in whole).

So, my questions are

- Is there any better mechanism already present, that i am not aware of, that makes it easier, especially to keep track of specific answers that might address the two problems that i have stated above?
- Also, is there a way to search through just the text of my favourites?

Answer (score 3):

Like you said, starring a question to favorite it is the best way to track it as if you owned the question -- that is, you will be notified of new answers and edits to the question.

As for searching through your favorites try the search options page

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

specifically you want `infavorites:1`

Note that you can also sort your favorites tab by activity; the topmost favorite in that sort order is the one with the most recently active.

Comment: I will try out the `infavorites` search. Regarding sorting the favourites, the thing is that if i add all questions having answers i am keen to retain for reference, they neednt even be recently active anyways. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Tried out the `infavorites` search. That helps bigtime.

Comment: The option `infavorites:1` (or was it `infavorites:mine`) is [no longer supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76449/new-meta-search-engine-help-us-test) since the new search was introduced early 2011.

Comment: `infavorites:mine` is back: [A new search engine for Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange)