# Would like ability to "favorite" an answer

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mark Answer as Favorite / Star](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star)

I have found in several cases that while the question itself is not particularly interesting, one of the provided answers contains fantastic information that I would consider 'favoriting'.  In some of these cases it is not even the accepted answer that I would wish to favorite.

***I think a really good answer deserves as much recognition as a really good question***.

So I ask that the ability to 'favorite' an answer be added along with badges recognizing levels of accumulated favorite answers.

Comment: I think this should be on MSO, thus the vote to migrate

Answer (score 14):

I am highly in favour of an option to "favorite" an answer. The question asked is merely an impetus to the real goal: a quality answer. It is the answers that supply the valuable information in the SE network.