# We need a 'bookmark answer' link underneath the answer

Tags: feature-request, answers, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mark Answer as Favorite / Star](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star)

When I find a useful answer I like to bookmark the actual answer in my browser, not the link to the whole page with questions and answers I have to sift through again. So I right click on the 'share' link and go Bookmark This Link, eg:

[image: current bookmark link]

This brings up a window like this.

[image: bookmark dialogue]

This 'share' bookmark title isn't very useful as I have to type the bookmark title and keywords manually from memory which isn't easy as you can't copy paste from the webpage in the background as it's a modal dialogue.

It would be better if there was a 'bookmark answer' icon or link underneath the post which did this for you in one step. Then you end up with the title and keywords pre-filled out automatically for you. e.g.

[image: how it should look]

It could probably be done with a bit of JavaScript.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a dupe to me. This user _wants_ to bookmark the post in his browser, and is requesting an improvement to the "bookmark text." The other one merely acknowledges bookmarking an answer in a browser as a workaround to the feature he really wants, favoriting answers.

Comment: Yeah this request is not a duplicate @random. I'm asking for a more useful way to bookmark *in the web browser's bookmarks* including keywords etc not for favouriting links using the favourite system on the stackexchange websites. Reopen my post please.

Comment: That's adding another link to the post, which means UI is affected