# Favoriting Answers

Tags: feature-request, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mark Answer as Favorite / Star](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star)

I was wondering if it would be possible to favorite an answer...when I favorite a question it is useful to keep track of that entire question, but when I really just like an answer, and maybe it's not the top or accepted answer, it would be helpful to be able to favorite it