# Watch or favorite answers, not just questions

Tags: feature-request, notifications, bookmarks

Often I will have downvoted an answer shortly after it is posted, or commented on an answer suggesting some improvement or addition, and want to follow up later and see if my input has been acted upon, so that I can retract my downvote or take further action as appropriate. (Aside: do others do this, or am I a sad obsessive?)

Currently, I can favorite the question that the answer was on, both as a reminder to myself that I'm interested in it and in order to get notified when something changes, and I do so, but it's not an ideal solution when I'm only interested in a single answer on the page, for two reasons:

1. It generates noise that I'm not interested in on my favorites tab, as I get notified whenever *anything* on the question or the other answers there gets modified, not just stuff on the answer I'm interested in.
2. When I do come to have a look at the question, I've frequently forgotten which answer I'm interested in or why the heck I ever favorited this question in the first place.

*(I realise that [favoriting answers has been requested before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star), but since it was a long time ago, my particular use case for the request was not discussed, and I think notifications on favorites weren't even implemented yet back then, I figured it was reasonable to start another thread for this request. Feel free to downvote or close if you think my doing so wasn't appropriate.)*

The ability to favorite answers would solve this use case for me. Is there any chance we could get this feature?

Comment: we're all obsessives in this regard.

Comment: As a workaround, the -1 rep line item on the [Reputation report](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1709587/mark-amery?tab=reputation) can be used as a pointer to downvoted answers.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Not a great workaround, though. Firstly, it doesn't give me notifications, and secondly, I only want to watch a (fairly small) subset of the answers I downvote.

Comment: Huh... I know I said "feel free to vote to close if you think this question wasn't appropriate", but I was hoping that some of those voting to close would at least offer some justification for doing so, especially given that I gave an explanation for why I figured that opening a new question for this issue was reasonable. :/