# Clicking on a negatively-received, grayed-out answer no longer permanently removes the graying-out

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, answers, down-votes

Answers that are of sufficient negative score are grayed out when viewed. If one wants to more easily read the answer, they can mouse over the answer content, and it will no longer be grayed out for so long as the mouse cursor is over it.

Previously, though, it used to be that *clicking* (not merely hovering over) a grayed-out answer's body would permanently remove the graying-out, so that it would no longer be gray even if the mouse cursor is moved away from the answer body. (This would last until the page was refreshed or the answer was clicked on again.)

This feature was very useful as the graying-out makes the answer harder to read (as the contrast ratio is reduced greatly), and I wouldn't have to continuously hover over the answer to be able to read it. (This is especially important if the negatively-received answer contains a quote - as quotes are now grayed-out, the graying-out of the answer means that quotes in such answers are now double-grayed-out, making them almost completely unreadable.)

Can this please be added back?

Comment: Can confirm, just did it with [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star/107790#107790) post.

Comment: I thought this was a weird browser quirk that went away after some recent update. Good to know that it was an SE feature. +1, please bring back the click!

Comment: For a simple fix, you can keep the cursor at the left of the post (along the vote column, it will continue to un-gray). I do not know if it is a bug because since the last 3 months, only hovering over the answer works.

Comment: We're going to look into this as part of our regular bug duty rotation. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 8):

Clicking on a greyed-out downvoted answer (opacity: 50%) will now revert the text to normal (opacity: 100%) until the next page load.

> downvoted answer
> low opacity annoys
> click once, normal text

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362213/can-clicking-on-a-negatively-received-post-remove-the-graying-out-on-both-the-co

Comment: In the past, clicking it *again* would reinstate the graying-out. Has this been re-implemented?

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog According to this answer, no: “revert the text to normal (opacity: 100%) **until the next page load**”

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog consider it to be `status-planned`