# Can clicking on a negatively-received post remove the graying-out on both the content *and* the comments?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, answers, down-votes

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355103/clicking-on-a-negatively-received-grayed-out-answer-no-longer-permanently-remov) post was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) – and it is, to a degree.  But clicking on a post with a score of −3 ([or −7](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A..-7%20is%3Aa)) or lower doesn't remove the grayness *on the comments* underneath the post, only the answer content.  Can we extend the click-remove-grayness function to the comments as well?

Comment: Retagging as a bug, as it used to work with the comments in the past.

Comment: User cards are also affected (post owner and editor)

Comment: Interestingly, clicking on a comment permanently removes the “graying-out” on the post above, but not the comments!