# Separate "share" from "direct link"

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, sharing

## Background

Often I wish to quote other answers in my own answers or comments, at that time I need a direct link to the answer. That is of course what the share button is for.

[image]

## Crazy work arounds

However, until today I was unaware of its use and would use mad work arounds to get a direct link to the answer, these included:

- Clicking the edit history and then return to answer
- If no edit history (and I hated this one) going to the answerer's profile and find the answer there

## Share as a social networking word

I think its fair to say that the word "Share" is heavily associated with social networks and what I was expecting to find under the share button was facebook, twitter etc logos that would post the answer to those services; this wasn't what I wanted so I never clicked the button. The "share" button actually does have these logos but it also has a direct link to the answer

## Proposal

I would suggest separating out the "share" button from a new "direct link" button to avoid this confusion. Or alternatively renaming the "share" button to indicate its dual use.

## Justification

Since the [original feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156/would-it-be-helpful-to-be-able-to-link-to-specific-answers) request to add this direct link, several people have been confused sufficiently to post questions to find how to get direct links

- [How can I link to a specific answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45597/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-answer?lq=1)
- [Would it be helpful to be able to link to specific answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156/would-it-be-helpful-to-be-able-to-link-to-specific-answers?lq=1)

An interesting question (that I have no answer for) is of the people who need a link to an answer what proportion are sending to a social network and what proportion are reposting on stack exchange itself. The button seems to designed primarily for the first use case with the second use case as a secondary function.

Comment: My +1 goes for more clear name, not for separate buttons. But I agree *something* should be corrected if it causes problems. Personally I do my best to keep myself away from social networks, and my browser filters filter away most of FB-related stuff, so share was not confusing to me. I just never got used to any particular meaning ;)

Comment: I think it is a good idea to separate permalink from share functionality. Most news pages i visit provide a permalink at the bottom of the news post and also functionality to share the post to Social networks (FB, Google, etc.)

Comment: Since you were unaware of direct links to a post, I should also mention that direct links to comments also exist. :) Click on the time stamps after any comment and you get a direct link to that comment.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Yeah, i was aware of those, its a bizarre way to get the link but as comments are "not important" and linked to rarely I’m more content with that

Comment: The first version of the "share" was simply "link" - it was changed [about a year ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140905/152859).

Comment: We could keep the `share` link in place, but move the permalink to a small icon next to `flag`. That might reduce visual clutter.

Comment: If we did have separate share / link buttons I guess the difference would be the share credits you with the share (includes your user id at the end) whereas the link doesn't (no user id).