# Extra Share option to refer to other's answer within the same question

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, share-this

When answering  (or sometimes commenting) I often want to refer to other's answer within the same question  ( like discussed in [How to refer to a different answer or comment when answering a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133266/how-to-refer-to-a-different-answer-or-comment-when-answering-a-question)). 
I need to copy author name first, add "'s answer" and then copy the URL of the answer.

It will be nice to have it as an additional format of the "share" pop up that will generate `[AuthorName's answer](full-URL-of-the-answer)`

Other suggestions, that can be considered to implement at the same time.
[Please make links to other answers in the same question link to the anchor instead of the full URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58645/please-make-links-to-other-answers-in-the-same-question-link-to-the-anchor-inste?rq=1)

[Separate "share" from "direct link"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201861/separate-share-from-direct-link)

[Provide an easily discoverable way to get the full URL to an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114088/provide-an-easily-discoverable-way-to-get-the-full-url-to-an-answer/114116#114116)

Comment: Well, many times I prefer something like "see this other answer", without giving a name. Many people are using a "fake" name, and many people keep changing their display name often, rendering it pointless to mention them in such a way.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I noticed that you used "existing answer" in comment http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193594/improve-the-usability-intuitiveness-of-direct-comment-links/280567#comment911048_280567 and I had to open the link to find which of answers you are talking about. Name of answer's author is a way to identify the answer. It doesn't matter Is it a real name or fake one, whatever they like to name themselves. I do not expect that people changing names too often, but if they do, it will be breaking change for the title of my link. It's not critical.